# Unable to get access token from Workday's OAuth2 token endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, workday-api

I'm trying to implement an OAuth 2 client to Workday and I'm getting hung up on trying to request a token.  I can call the authorization endpoint and it redirects to my callback with the authorization code just fine, but when I try to post the authorization code to the token endpoint, I get:

```
"{\"error\" : \"application=service - invalid_request\"}"
```

I've tried different combinations of URL encoding on the request_uri.  I've tried passing a state parameter.  I've even gone as far to proxy the call to make sure the I was actually sending the correct information.  Here is the PHP code I wrote to try and retrieve the token.

```
function callback() {
    $code = $_GET["code"];
    log_message('info', 'Using code: ' . $code);
    $url = "https://wd5-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/oauth2/<redacted>/token";
    $data = array(
            'client_id' => '<redacted>',
            'client_secret' => '<redacted>',
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'code' => $code,
            'redirect_uri' => 'https://<redacted>/account/callback'
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    log_message('info', json_encode(curl_getinfo($curl)));

    curl_close($curl);

    log_message('info', json_encode($result));
    #redirect(base_url()."account/login");
}
```

I'm kind of at a lost as to what is wrong.  I've combed all the forums and I've tried to compare against conversations regarding other OAuth 2 servers, but I cannot find anything on my specific problem.  Has anyone else successfully done this with Workday?

Comment: I know this question is old, but did you setup the API Client in Workday?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
it worked for me:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://wd2-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/oauth2/ <tenant> /token \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic T0RJM1pqa3pZbVV0WXpBeU15MDBZV0kwTFRnMU4yRXROV1UyTW1Wak16ZzFNamxqOmNudzZwbDI3Zmc4eG54YWIxamE1cWR6cHlqMGtkZW9mdmNubjF0czhyN3U2OHpiZ3llOTJyajZvbWhiMjY3ZjlrYzE0ajU3d3F5cHQyNjN5Ymc3N3h3ZXdvc3h2bmVodTc1Mw==' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Host: wd2-impl-services1.workday.com' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-length: 60' \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=4pwzdn1vs63alnm1fyas62za6'
```

Its result is:

```
{
    "refresh_token": "r50ditl18yt0osdfnoasdsadfouwerljsdfkauooiu5h5hvanlkf8ow5n9ugjc3d8wiz99c6xxbi2t8ruqhxhohfzl4jfmuy",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "e1zrm1ccwb9werwer6upb3tkp"
}
```